# System.NullReferenceException in while using Linq Xamarin

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin

**Solved**

I have a SQLite Table created from a **class** named **Strategy**, which has two properties `String StrategyCode` and `String StrategyID`. I am Binding the StrategyCode Column to a Spinner with this code.

```
private void BindList()
{
    try
    {
        var list = connection.Query<Strategy>("SELECT StrategyCode FROM Strategy");
        BindStrategy = list.ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));
        var StratAdpater = new ArrayAdapter<System.String>(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, BindStrategy);
        StratAdpater.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);
        spinner2.Adapter = StratAdpater;       
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

I have a **textview** right below this Spinner, Where, i want to show the `StrategyID` of the corresponding StrategyCode selected from the Spinner. This is How I am doing it.

```
try
 {
   var selectedstrat = spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString();
   var userselection = (from a in connection.Table<Strategy>()
                                     where a.StrategyCode == selectedstrat
                                     select a);            
    strategyID.Text = userselection.FirstOrDefault().StrategyID;
 }
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

But i am getting a System.NullReferenceException - (Object Reference not Set to Instance of an Object) and the StrategyID is not getting set onto the Textview. But, When i HardCode the `StrategyCode` value For Example:

```
var userselection = (from a in connection.Table<Strategy>()
                                         where a.StrategyCode == "Strategy1"
                                         select a);
```

Then the TextView Shows the ID of the Hardcoded Strategy. What is Possibly Going Wrong Here? 
I tried this

```
 var userselection = (from a in connection.Table<Strategy>()
                                         where a.StrategyCode == selectedstrat
                                         select a.StrageyID).FirstOrDefault();

                    StrategyID.Text = userselection.ToString();
```

But Still i am not able to get the StrategyID on the TextView.

Comment: Where are you getting exception?

Comment: Your "a" is coming where, and when you do where on it, it is bound to throw exception

Comment: @Arvindraja When i went into the debugging mode The "selectedstrat" has the value from the spinner but when i am tring to display the ID on the TextView it is showing an error.

Comment: @saketkumar i didn't get you?

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this line:

`var userselection = (from a in connection.Table<Strategy>()
                                         where a.StrategyCode == selectedstrat
                                         select a.StrageyID).FirstOrDefault();`

What if `userselection` is `null`?

`StrategyID.Text = userselection.ToString();
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- null => throws`

Comment: Yes! UserSelection is null but it is Null only when i am passing 'selectedstrat', when i pass a hardcoded strategy it is not null.